# collapse columns of a list of matrices using for loop

Tags: r, list, loops

I created a list of matrices from all possible combinations of a set of letters:

```
vec = c('a', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'p')
```

Now, I want to loop within each list (lists have different number of rows and columns) in order to collapse rows in each column of every list:

```
temp= list(); def= list()
for (i in 1:length(vec)){
temp[[i]] <- combn(vec, i) # all combinations
for (j in 1:ncol(temp[[i]])){
def[[i]] <- matrix(paste(temp[[i]][, j], collapse=''), byrow=T)
}}
```

However, I only get the last column of each matrix. For example the combinations of 2 elements are:

```
temp[[2]]
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "a"  "e"  "e"  "e"  "g"  "g"  "i"  
[2,] "e"  "g"  "i"  "p"  "g"  "i"  "p"  "i"  "p"  "p"
```

And I want my output to be:

```
def[[2]]
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "ae"  "ag"  "ai"  "ap"  "eg"  "ei"  "ep"  "gi"  "gp"  "ip"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure that this is what you are looking for, but `combn` has it own `FUN` argument. That means you can apply a function to each combination (see `?combn` for details):

```
combn(vec, 2, paste0, collapse="")
#  [1] "ae" "ag" "ai" "ap" "eg" "ei" "ep" "gi" "gp" "ip"

def <- lapply(seq_along(vec), function(i)combn(vec, i, paste0, collapse=""))
def 
# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "e" "g" "i" "p"
# 
# [[2]]
#  [1] "ae" "ag" "ai" "ap" "eg" "ei" "ep" "gi" "gp" "ip"
# 
# [[3]]
#  [1] "aeg" "aei" "aep" "agi" "agp" "aip" "egi" "egp" "eip" "gip"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "aegi" "aegp" "aeip" "agip" "egip"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "aegip"
#
```

BTW: the problem of your code is in the following line:

```
def[[i]] <- matrix(paste(temp[[i]][, j], collapse=''), byrow=T)
```

You always overwrite the results from the previous pasting (that's why you always get the last column).

Comment: Great! it was what I was looking for